# Node.js javascript: Reduce Array of Object by Multiple Key Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, filter

I have the following array of objects in a Node.js script:

```
[ 
{ 
    start: '10-05-2018',    
    assigned_agent: '1257434'
     },
  { 
    start: '10-05-2018',
    assigned_agent: '1257434'
    },
  { 
    start: '10-05-2018',
    assigned_agent: '1257434'
   },
  { 
    start: '10-06-2018',    
    assigned_agent: '1257434'
    },
  { 
    start: '10-05-2018',   
    assigned_agent: '1277852'
     },
  { 
    start: '10-05-2018',
    assigned_agent: '1277852'
  }
 ]
```

What I need is to have this grouped by the start and assigned_agent keys. I have tried `filter` function examples but no luck. Not, there are other key/value pairs in the array but omitting them for the sake of clarity. Also, while this is a Node.js script I do have Lodash available if that helps.

Thank you.

Comment: You want the `reduce` method, not filter, if you want to group them.

Comment: Thank you. So this should be a simple solution then.

Comment: Yep, one by which you should be able to make an attempt at yourself.

Comment: var arr_new =  Object.values(obj_agents_routes.reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, { [cur.assigned_agent, cur.start]: cur }), {}));

Comment: has unexpected token error. I need to figure out 'reduce' per multiple values.

Comment: At the very least, show us what your expected output is!

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had explained it well and two other people had no issues picking up the simple object which needed to be reduced. Didn't want to make the Question any longer than needed. But next time will be more careful. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with using lodash, try `groupBy`

```js
const data = [
  { start: "10-05-2018", assigned_agent: "1257434" },
  { start: "10-05-2018", assigned_agent: "1257434" },
  { start: "10-05-2018", assigned_agent: "1257434" },
  { start: "10-06-2018", assigned_agent: "1257434" },
  { start: "10-05-2018", assigned_agent: "1277852" },
  { start: "10-05-2018", assigned_agent: "1277852" },
]

const group_by_both = _.chain(data)
  .groupBy((el) => `${el.start} ${el.assigned_agent}`)
  .values()
  .value()

console.log(group_by_both)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am okay with Lodash but I need to group by both values for each array pair. Let me try your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, your answer is sort of working but unneccesarily appending: 
{ '10-05-2018 1257434':
   [ {

Comment: @IrfanClemson you could get rid of it by extracting value using _.values()

Comment: Hi, please update your answer and I will accept it. I think I am almost there. Thank you!

Comment: @IrfanClemson just updated, you could have a look at it

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [{
    start: '10-05-2018',
    assigned_agent: '1257434'
  },
  {
    start: '10-05-2018',
    assigned_agent: '1257434'
  },
  {
    start: '10-05-2018',
    assigned_agent: '1257434'
  },
  {
    start: '10-06-2018',
    assigned_agent: '1257434'
  },
  {
    start: '10-05-2018',
    assigned_agent: '1277852'
  },
  {
    start: '10-05-2018',
    assigned_agent: '1277852'
  }
];

var grouped = data.reduce((accumulator, element) => {
    // group by start and agent, so combine values for unique key
    var key = element.start + element.assigned_agent;
    
    // if there is not already a grouping, make an empty array
    accumulator[key] = accumulator[key] || [];
    
    // add the element to the desired group
    accumulator[key].push(element);
    
    // return the accumulator for the next iteration
    return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help! I had started on the @hgb123 answer already. Pretty sure your's would have helped too. Thank you again!